Experiencing Micro-Outages Over VPN Tunnel: Any Suggestions?
We are experiencing network issues between one of our instances and a client, connected via a VPN tunnel. These issues result in 3 to 4 network micro-outages per day. During these micro-outages, our SaaS application becomes inaccessible, causing significant disruption.
How can we effectively detect and visualize such micro-outages? Has anyone else experienced similar issues, and are there best practices or tools to analyze and mitigate these problems?
Thank you for your insights.

I would first check your internet connection gear to make sure it's clean there, ask a higher end support on your ISP side to check it.
If it's a cabled connection it can happen, as the modem can flap for some millisecond on bad connection, the signal get resynced and reconnect.
It's invisible to most user, but not to a VPN tunnel, as the loss of packet will force the tunnel to re-negotiate. VPN tunnel are more sensible to that.
It happened to me in the past on a cable connection, as in the pocket they were a bad signal on the return signal, the modem was forced to stop and resync the signal with the central multiple time per day, thus creating a micro cut each time for the VPN, but not enought big to cause a loss of internet on the monitoring tool, but the modem will show a high load of uncorrected codewords rx on it.

Our server is hosted on GCP, so we don’t have a modem or local internet connection on our side. However, the client, who is experiencing these issues, is on a fiber-optic connection. Based on your experience, do you think such micro-cuts could still happen on a fiber connection? And if so, what kind of diagnostic steps or metrics could help identify whether the issue is with the client’s ISP or somewhere in the VPN tunnel configuration?
Are there specific tools or techniques you’d recommend to monitor and confirm whether the VPN tunnel is renegotiating due to packet loss? Thank you !

@SarayHach: packet loss can also occur due to insufficient capacity at any point along the way. Going from no tools to something like PingPlotter would probably reveal a lot.
